# Administrator checkbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I was wondering if I can somehow reduce administrator access rights to a user eventhough ive checked this user as an administrator.

Ive read that once a user is checked as an administrator he has full rights regardless the security editor but I wanted to make sure that there really isnt any "easy" way how to restrict his access.

Why am I asking? A client wants to create a few new users (administrators) but at the same time he doesnt want them to be able to use File Explorer. If I could somehow manage this from Core database that would be neat.

Thank you very much for any comments.

Martin

Comment: Would removing the file explorer application be an option?

Comment: Interesting, to be honest i havent thought of this option. The only reason why we keep the File Explorer app available is to be able to fix some criticals in config ASAP in case the third party which takes care of the servers and deploys would be unavailable. I would call it an emergency policy. Thanks for your idea, i guess what you suggest is the only way out...